# Proving an Equation by Induction

Tags: induction

I'm trying to prove the following equation by mathematical induction but I'm stuck on the last part. How do I get (k+1)^2 (k+2)^2?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(k+1)^3$ on second line left hand (i.e. second summand) from word "Assume" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this because you are apparently studying a Math analysis written by someone who is in the wrong line of work. I regard the whole analysis as poorly written.  This is how I would express it.

You are trying to prove by induction that for all $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$, that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}. \tag1 $$

(1) above is true for $n=1$.

Assume that (1) above is true for $n=N$, and then prove that (1) above is also true for $n=(N+1)$.

You have that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N+1} i^3 = \left[\sum_{i=1}^N i^3\right] + (N+1)^3. \tag2 $$

By inductive assumption the first term (i.e. the summation) on the RHS equals

$$\frac{N^2(N+1)^2}{4}. \tag3 $$

The 2nd RHS term equals

$$(N+1)^2 \times (N+1) = \frac{4(N+1)^2(N+1)}{4}. \tag4 $$

Examining (3) and (4) you notice that they each have the common factor of $\displaystyle ~\frac{(N+1)^2}{4}.$

Therefore, when you combine the expressions in (3) and (4) above, you have:

$$\frac{(N+1)^2}{4} \times \left[N^2 + 4N + 4\right]. \tag5 $$

(5) above may be re-expressed as

$$\frac{(N+1)^2(N+2)^2}{4}. \tag6 $$

Putting (6) and (2) together, you have that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N+1} i^3 = \frac{(N+1)^2(N+2)^2}{4}. \tag7 $$

Setting $K = N+1$, (7) above may be re-expressed as

$$\sum_{i=1}^K i^3 = \frac{K^2(K+1)^2}{4}.$$

This is consistent with the original assertion that was expressed in (1) above.  Therefore, if the assertion is true for $n=N$, then the assertion is true for $n=(N+1).$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4}+(k+1)^3=(k+1)^2\left[ \frac{k^2}{4}+k+1\right]=\\
=\frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2 }{4}$$